# Android Sherlock theme Dialog with Round Corners

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have created an Activity with a custom layout, in the manifest file i declare a theme as

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog"
```

This make the activity popup like a Dialog. What i want is the dialog to have rounded corners.

Is there any way for me to do this ?

Kind Regards